# Radio button validation (alert box) confirmation and rejection

Tags: javascript, html, function, validation, radio-button

I'm working on a HTML document which is an exam submission form. I've completed almost all of the set tasks however, I'm having trouble validating radio buttons. I've searched on stackoverflow however, the answers do not meet the criteria of the question. My completed code is shown below.

I'm having trouble with the bold part of this task:

Add a set of radio buttons to the form to accept a level of entry such as GCSE, AS or A2. **Write a function that displays the level of entry to the user in an alert box so that the level can be confirmed or rejected.**

Below is the code working, excluding the validation of the radio buttons. Seperatley, I have the code which doesn't work when implemented into the function validateForm().

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Exam entry</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {

var result = true;
var msg = "";




if (document.ExamEntry.name.value == "") {
msg += "You must enter your name \n";
document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
document.getElementById('name').style.color = "red";
result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value == "") {
msg += "You must enter the subject \n";
document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
document.getElementById('subject').style.color = "red";
result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.examno.value == "") {
msg += "You must enter your Examination Number \n";
document.ExamEntry.examno.focus();
document.getElementById('examinationno').style.color = "red";
result = false;
}
if (document.ExamEntry.examno.value.length!== 4) {
            msg+="Your Examination Number should be 4 digits.\n";
            document.ExamEntry.examno.focus();
            document.getElementById('examinationno').style.color="red";
            result = false;
        }


if(msg==""){
return result;
}
{
alert(msg)
return result;
}
}
</script>
    </head> 

    <body>
        <h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>

<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
    <table width="50%" border="0">
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="name">Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="subject">Subject</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="subject" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="examinationno">Examination Number</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="examno" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="examtype" value="GCSE" />GCSE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="examtype" value="AS" />AS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="examtype" value="A2" />A2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onClick="return validateForm();" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Based on the current code, why won't the following validate when added into the function?:

```
if(document.getElementById('GCSE').checked)
{examtype = "GCSE";
}
if(document.getElementById('AS').checked)
{examtype = "AS";
}
if(document.getElementById('A2').checked)
{examtype = "A2";
}

if(confirm("You have selected"+examtype+.Continue?")){

if(msg==""){
return result;
}
{

alert(msg)
return result;
}
}

else{
alert("Action cancelled");
return false;
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? Also, there is an error in the confirm message that is highlighted by SO.

Comment: This isn't a homework question, it's a research task where internet use is essential. What is the error with the confirm message? Also I'm not familiar with 'SO'? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I'm not sure where one acquires a "research task where internet use is essential" in Javascript, but this task looks largely like a homework problem. With that, I see you are a new user, so I have nothing indicating that this is or isn't a homework question. So, I will simply point to where the error is and hope you can figure it out. Look at the `if (confirm...) {` and watch the color of the text. Then look at the quotation marks.

Comment: Validation should listen on the form's summit handler, not submit button's click handler since forms can be submitted without clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Retrieving the checked radio button value
function getRadioValue (frmName, rbGroupName) 
{
    var radios = document[frmName].elements[rbGroupName];
    for (var i=0; i <radios.length; i++) 
    {
        if (radios[i].checked) 
        {
          return radios[i].value;       
        }
    }

    return false;
 }
```

Call the **getRadioValue()** inside **validateForm()**

```
 // examtype gets false or GCSE or AS or A2
 var examtype = getRadioValue ("ExamEntry", "examtype");
```

Comment: Given that the caller already knows the form and radio button group names, probably easier to just pass the collection: `getRadioValue(radioButtonCollection)`. :-)

Comment: Thank you for this, there seems to be some conflict when adding into the current function validateForm(). Just calling the var examtype = getRadioValue ("ExamEntry", "examtype"); in the function validateForm() causes the validation to follow through to the success page.

Answer (score 0):

"Continue" is a keyword. So you have to wrap it in apostrophes("). I could not get the structure of if-statements, I made some changes. I hope this is what you are looking for..

```
   if(confirm("You have selected"+examtype+". Continue?")){

    if(msg==""){
    alert(msg);
    return result;
    }

    else{
    alert("Action cancelled");
    return false;
    }
}
```